# NodeBox error for a verb in python

Tags: python, nodebox

I downloaded the package http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation
I'm getting an error even when I tried to get a tense of a verb .

```
import en
print en.is_verb('use')
#prints TRUE

print en.verb.tense('use')

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/cse/version2_tense.py in <module>()
----> 1 
      2 
      3 
      4 
      5 

/home/cse/en/__init__.pyc in tense(self, word)
    124 
    125     def tense(self, word):
--> 126         return verb_lib.verb_tense(word)
    127 
    128     def is_tense(self, word, tense, negated=False):

/home/cse/en/verb/__init__.pyc in verb_tense(v)
    175 
    176     infinitive = verb_infinitive(v)
--> 177     a = verb_tenses[infinitive]
    178     for tense in verb_tenses_keys:
    179         if a[verb_tenses_keys[tense]] == v:

KeyError: ''
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because there is a mistake in the `~/Library/Application Support/NodeBox/en/verb/verb.txt` file they are using to create the dictionary.

use is the [**`infinitive`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive) form, however, "used" is entered as the infinitive.

**at line 5857:**

`used,,,uses,,using,,,,,used,used,,,,,,,,,,,,`

**should be:**

`use,,,uses,,using,,,,,used,used,,,,,,,,,,,,`

**after editing and saving the file:**

```
import en

print en.is_verb("use")
print en.verb.infinitive('use')
print en.verb.tense('use')
```

gives:

```
True
use
infinitive
```

**extra:**

```
import en

print 'use    %s' % en.verb.tense("use")
print 'uses   %s' % en.verb.tense("uses")
print 'using  %s' % en.verb.tense('using')
print 'used   %s' % en.verb.tense('used')

use    infinitive
uses   3rd singular present
using  present participle
used   past
```